# Add another sheet to excel export from PHP

Tags: php, excel

First, I have a few knowledge in PHP, and that is all I could do with my excel export (see attached code below)

It works, but I want to export that excel file with 2 more sheets, I've googled a lot but could not customize the code to insert in it, please, help me if you can

Thank you

```
<?php

$filename =  time().".csv";
header ( 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' );
header ( 'Date: ' . date ( 'D M j G:i:s T Y' ) );
header ( 'Last-Modified: ' . date ( 'D M j G:i:s T Y' ) );
header ( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel') ;
header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);

ExportFile1($main_exce);

    function ExportFile1($records) {
        
        $do = false;
            if(!empty($records)){

            foreach($records as $down){

          $heading = true;
              foreach($down as $row) {
                if($heading) {
                  // display field/column names as a first row
                    $heading = false;
                    if(!$do){
                      $d = implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
                     print chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($d, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');      
                     $do = true;
                     }
                }else{
                    $d = implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";  
                      print chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($d, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');   
              }
            }
          //  $d = "\t\n\t\n\t\n";
           // print chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($d, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'); 



                    

                }


            }

           }

           exit;             



?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't make this work is that you are not creating an Excel export here.

You're creating a plain-text, tab-delimited file. Excel can import files in that format, but it's not a true Excel file. It's a simple flat file, and as such, it doesn't support multiple worksheets, unlike a real Excel file.

If you want to solve this, you need to rewrite this code so that it outputs a file which is in the real Excel file format - it's considerably more complex than a tab-delimited text format. There are various libraries available for PHP which can help you easily create real Excel files in `xlsx` format. Recommendations are off-topic here but they are not hard to find using a search engine.